# React component offers API. I'm not understanding how to make API calls to a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The package I'm looking at is: https://github.com/hawkrives/react-list-select

I don't understand how you can use the listed methods. For example:

**.select(index)**

- number index - items array index

Select an item from the list

Are these meant to be passed as properties? Otherwise I'm not understand how they're meant ot be used. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html